# Generalization of integrating factor?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For example, if we have $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$, we can obtain $\mu(x)=e^{\int p(x)dx}$ as integrating factor. My question is: exist a generalization of this? ie, if I have $y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+...+p_0(x)y=q(x)$, exist a "integrating factor" for this?

Comment: Did you try to evaluate and use it for $n=2$?

Comment: Use what? For n=2 I have two p(x)

Comment: I try to find \mu(x) such that \mu(x)(y^{(n)}...)=(\mu(x)q(x))^{(n)} but didn't work :(

Comment: Most textbooks on ordinary differential equations have several generalizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrating factor for higher order equations like $y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+...+p_0(x)y=q(x)$ does exist, for example one integrating factor of $y''+V(y)=0$ is $y'$, because $y'y''+V(y)y'=0$ can be integrated to get 
$$ \frac{1}{2}y'^2 + \int V(y) = C,$$
from which you can write $y'$ in terms of $y$ and integrate again.

In general the integrating factor is a function $\mu\big(x,y,y',\cdots,y^{(n-1)}\big)$ such that there exists another function $\Psi(x,y,y',\cdots,y^{(n-1)})$, such that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\Psi(x,y,\cdots,y^{(n-1)}) = \mu\big(x,y,\cdots,y^{(n-1)}\big)\big(y^{(n)}+p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}+...+p_0(x)y-q(x)\big),$$
where $\frac{d}{dx}$ is the total derivative (like $\frac{d}{dx}(x+y+y'^2)=1+y'+2y'y''$) instead of the partial derivative. For higher order equations, you can find integrating factors systematically by using the so called *symmetry methods* originated by Norwegian mathematician Sophus Lie. Details can be found in books like [Symmetry and integration methods for differential equations](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Symmetry-Integration-Methods-Differential-Equations/dp/1441931473/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1450691246&sr=8-2&keywords=Symmetry%20and%20integration%20methods%20for%20differential%20equations) by Bluman and Anco or [Symmetry Methods for Differential Equations](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Symmetry-Methods-Differential-Equations-Mathematics/dp/0521497035/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1450690208&sr=8-1&keywords=symmetry%20methods%20for%20differential%20equations) by Hydon (the function $\Psi$ is usually called a first integral).